# Print fetched data with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to make chat room with ajax. Till now I am able to store data in db without page load. And also able to fetch data and display onscreen using ajax. Here is what I did with ajax

```
$('#chat').submit(function(){
 var chatmsg = $("#chatmsg").val();       //chat message from input field
 var chatroomid = $("#chatroomid").val();   //hidden input field
   $.ajax({
       url: baseurl+'User_dash/chatmessage',  //An function in ctroller which contains only insert query
       type: 'post',
       data: {chatmsg:chatmsg, chatroomid:chatroomid},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (argument) {
         if(argument['status']){                 
         
                $("#chatting").append(" <li id='"+getvalue+"'>"+argument['msg']+"</li>."); //Here I am printing chat message which resently submitted in database
                
            }
         }
       },
       error: function (hrx, ajaxOption, errorThrow) {
           console.log(ajaxOption);
           console.log(errorThrow)
       }
   });
   return false; 
 });
```

This method with ajax is working fine. But issue I faced here is that, this display chat message only to current user. Not to other side of user whome message is being sent via chat.

To solve this issue I come up with one idea which doesn't seems to be working as I planed. Here it is how I modified my previous ajax code..

```
      $('#chat').submit(function(){
 var chatmsg = $("#chatmsg").val();       
   $.ajax({
       url: baseurl+'User_dash/chat',  //controller function which contains insert query, after that select query to fetch chat data from db and store in view
       type: 'post',
       data: {chatmsg:chatmsg},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (argument) {
         if(argument['status']){
             //Not doing anything here this time
         }
       },
       error: function (hrx, ajaxOption, errorThrow) {
           console.log(ajaxOption);
           console.log(errorThrow)
       }
   });
   return false; 
 });
```

In updated version of script I thought If I will call a controller function which is storing data in view (chat page) then It will run query and print data without page load.

But with this method, I am getting chat onscreen only after page load, although it is getting submit in db with ajax fine.

Here is controller code for my second method with ajax if needed

```
    public function chat(){
    
    if(!empty($_POST['chatmsg'])){
        
        $chatdata = array('CHAT_ROOM'=>$_POST['chatroomid'],
                        'VENDOR'=>$this->session->userdata('USER_ID'),
                        'BUYER'=>49,                        
                        'MESSAGE'=>$_POST['chatmsg']
                      );
                      
        $this->db->insert('tbl_chat', $chatdata); //inserting data          
    }
    
    $data['chatroom'] = $this->db->where('CHAT_ROOM', 1)->get('tbl_chat')->result_array(); //fetching data from db
    
    $this->load->view('userDash/chat', $data);      
}
```

How do I achieve to run insert and then select query and print data on screen without page load?

Where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue earlier, What I did was, just added this jquery script which keep refreshing (every second) a certain div inside page in which I have put query to fetch chat from db and printing them.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $("#chatting").load(location.href + " #chatting");
}, 1000);
```